# Painting on tiled textures

Tags: texturing, materials

for anyone who can help.
My question is about tiled textures.
Painting over or editing un-tiled textures goes smoothly, but when the texture is mapped then whatever strokes you add on top of the texture also get tiled.

Is there a way to paint without the strokes also being tiled?

[image]

Comment: Create another UV map

Comment: The default mapping for image textures is UV. If both images are using the same mapping you will get them "tiled"

Create a new UV map to use it to map the painted texture.

Comment: I appreciate the fast response.
What you said makes perfect sense.
Now for another beginner question since I could not find anything explaining how to do it online.
How do I create a New UV map?